# Problem setting up additional sites on IIS7

Tags: iis-7

We already have existing sites on our production server, a few using different ip addresses, a few using the same, all with different domain names.

Now we/I have 2 remaining sites to setup, but they keep re-occuring iis7 errors.

Showing that there is NTFS errors, can't login, or find the web.config file.

Even though the file is just right there.

I set up the app pool to use the app pool identity. Although I have tried putting is IUSR as well. But for some reason it just refuses to display anything other than the same 500 error.

Thank You.

Here is the screenshot of the error message i keep getting.
[image]

Comment: When you try to load the page does the AppPool stop or is it still running?

Comment: The other sites and apppools continue to run,but this one is unable to display the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an "old" issue, but do you have 1.1 and 2.0+ .Net Framework apps running in the same AppPool? You need to make sure the apps to seperate those versions, since they don't play nice. I also have had a few setups where the incorrect version of ASP.Net was targeted (1.1 instead of 3.5), which also caused errors.

Comment: I have a different app pool per site. I don't believe I have both .net frameworks. Do i need to change the mode of my app pool?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to change the AppPool then, but do verify that the ASP.Net runtime selected for the app matches what the app was built to run on. I've run into issues where I built it to run on the 2.0 framework, but IIS was telling it to run 1.1

Comment: Neither of the two sites I am trying to setup and get working, use or require any asp.net code.